# Optimizing LEFT JOIN speed in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to join six tables in `BigQuery`. Collectively the data totals 500mb, with each table containing thousands of rows. I'm attempting to `LEFT JOIN` the tables on a shared column. The query is currently estimating a run time of several weeks and times out long before it gets anywhere close to finishing. Is there a better way of optimizing this query?

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `report1` t1
LEFT JOIN
  `report2` t2
ON
  t1.campaignid = t2.campaignid
LEFT JOIN
  `report3` t3
ON
  t1.campaignid = t3.campaignid
LEFT JOIN
  `report4` t4
ON
  t1.campaignid = t4.campaignid
LEFT JOIN
  `report5` t5
ON
  t1.campaignid = t5.campaignid
LEFT JOIN
  `report6` t6
ON
  t1.campaignid = t6.campaignid
```

Comment: I would get all tables one by one and save as json all them. Then make a program in c# to access that json files. Then you can join your tables with LINQ. I'm not sure it is faster or slower but you can work on your data faster I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long for a comment.

The issue with your query is not the `left join`s *per se*.  Rather, the issue is (in all likelihood) that the underlying tables have multiple rows per `campaignid`.  You can get an estimate of the number of rows generated by the query by doing:

```
select sum(t1.cnt * t2.cnt * t3.cnt * t4.cnt * t5.cnt * t6.cnt)
from (select campaignid, count(*) as cnt from table1 group by 1) t1 left join
     (select campaignid, count(*) as cnt from table2 group by 1) t2 
     using (campaignid) left join
     (select campaignid, count(*) as cnt from table3 group by 1) t3 
     using (campaignid) left join
     (select campaignid, count(*) as cnt from table4 group by 1) t4 
     using (campaignid) left join
     (select campaignid, count(*) as cnt from table5 group by 1) t5 
     using (campaignid) left join
     (select campaignid, count(*) as cnt from table6 group by 1) t6 
     using (campaignid);
```

This will probably return a really large number -- which explains the long time for running the query.

You need to fix the `join` conditions or structure the query differently.  You might ask *another* question, with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the logic.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer - I'll see if I can restructure the query